# Can I run different versions of mysql on windows 7

Tags: mysql, database

I have windows 7 machine with 8GP RAM. Can I run mysql version 4 and 5.5.21 at the same time. If it is possible, please guide me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. But you will have to specify 2 different ports for running 2 different MySql Server  Instances. Default Port, i guess, for Mysql is 3306.

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple servers on Windows by starting them manually from the command line, each with appropriate operating parameters, or by installing several servers as Windows services and running them that way.

continue reading here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-windows-servers.html

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea behind this is to compile the new MySQL server with different TCP/IP ports and Unix socket files so that each one is listening on different network interfaces. Compiling in different base directories for each installation also results in separate compiled-in data directory, log file, and PID file location for each server.

Refer this link [also.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/multiple-windows-servers.html)

[How to install two different versions of MySQL server on the same PC](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/install-two-mysql.html)

Comment: Shouldn't *compile* be reworded to *install*?